# Regex multiple lines search, matched, but highlighted only what initially is on screen

Tags: regular-expression, highlight

Let's say I have the following fantasy code

```
// a long definition of a structure
struct long_struct {
    ...
};
```

There are tons of multiple lines inside such block of code. It cannot be displayed fully
within a single page, but spans across multiple pages.

I would like to highlight all the lines inside such `struct` definition without highlighting `struct long_struct {` and `};`. I successfully did it with the following regex

```
/\(^struct\s\+long_struct\s*{\n\)\@<=\(^.*\n\)\{-}\(^};\)\@=
```

(in short such regex makes use of positive lookbehind, and positive lookahead, with non-greedy `\{-}` search.)

But the problem is that it will only highlights those lines that are able to be fit within a single page height. If I reduce the font size of terminal to fit more lines, it would be able to highlights additional lines as well. So I believe it's not the problem about above regex pattern.

How can I make vim able to highlight all those lines without limited by the number of lines shown on terminal screen?

**Edit**:

For a test case, you can use this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/include/linux/sched.h), then apply the same regex pattern above but for `task_struct`.

Comment: How do you mean highlight? You can’t see something not on screen (though splits can help).

Comment: Hey @D.BenKnoble , by highlighting I mean just when you do normal search `/` and vim will highlight the search result and all occurrences. With that even when I move my cursor around, those highlighted occurrences from search are still there, highlighted, even not in current visible page.

Comment: I doubt multiline search would be highlighted more than some threshold (~a window height), you can use textproperties for that kind of highlighting

Comment: probably limits are similar to what is in this Q: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/highlighting-after-a-line-limit/31934

Comment: Thanks @MaximKim , also for info on `matchadd` which will limit to one screen highlighting. That seems like it. Using text property is somewhat overkill such that I have to implement a small function to achieve the same as normal search `/`. Anyway, I will explore more about text property, thanks for bringing such topic up!